# Protractor - Where to use browser.waitForAngular()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have some tests written using protractor for angular.js app. I am using `Page Objects` design pattern and there i have some methods that navigate to other pages by clicking on links and buttons. and soon after that i am calling `browser.waitForAngular()`.

**Page Object**

```
module.exports = function () {
    this.companyNameLink = element(by.id('viewCompany'));
    this.newMeetingButton = element(by.id('newMeetingButton'));

    this.createNewGeneralMeeting = function () {
        this.newMeetingButton.click();
        browser.waitForAngular();
    };

    this.goToCompanyPage = function () {
        this.companyNameLink.click();
        browser.waitForAngular();
    };
};
```

And in some spec file i use this page object like this..

```
var DashboardPage = require('../dashboardPageObject.js');
dashboardPage = new DashboardPage();

...

dashboardPage.goToCompanyPage();
```

But the problem is sometimes i get the `angular could not be found on the window` error and my tests fail. Most of the time the tests run. This issue is random. My question is that should i remove the `browser.waitForAngular()` from the page object method and call it after i make the method call like this...

**Modified Page Object**

```
...
this.goToCompanyPage = function () {
    this.companyNameLink.click();
};
...
```

**Spec File**

```
dashboardPage.goToCompanyPage();
browser.waitForAngular();
```

Is calling `browser.waitForAngular()` causing the issue? Where should i call `waitForAngular` is there any best practice on how to use this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From protractor's [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular):

> Instruct webdriver to wait until Angular has finished rendering and has no outstanding $http or $timeout calls before continuing. Note that Protractor automatically applies this command before every WebDriver action.

You shouldn't be calling this at all and I cannot think of a valid case where you should.

Comment: I have this use case as in, test the changes made on the page after refresh.  Make Changes -> click save (wont cause any page refresh) -> refresh -> test the reloaded page. In this case, refresh is triggered before save function is complete causing unnecessary browser alerts on the page. I had to use, waitForAngular() before triggering refresh on the page.

Comment: Well, if you do the refresh by calling `browser.refresh`, it should wait for the previous operation to finish automatically. I just looked at the code and verified that [it does](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3.0.0/lib/protractor.js#L726) (if you have not turned off the synchronization function that is). Maybe you caught a bug - you can file an issue in [protractor's github page](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues) if that's the case.

Comment: I am load data on a side async with angular. Using waitForAngular I can test the component. Otherwise protractor checks when no data is yet received

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using `waitForAngular`, you should handle the promise returned by `click`.

Thus, first of all, your page object methods should return those promises:

```
this.goToCompanyPage = function () {
    return this.companyNameLink.click();
};
```

Then, your actual use of this method can look like this:

```
dashboardPage.goToCompanyPage().then(function() {
  // this will be executed when the click is done.
  // No need for any waitForAngular.
});
```

For some further examples, see my [state/page-object version](https://github.com/avandeursen/angular-phonecat/pull/1) of the Angular PhoneCat Protractor test suite.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tried `button.click().then(() => {expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(newPageUrl);});` but I still get the old url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using browser.WaitForAngular() before navigating to a specific page via browser.Url
Otherwise, I get errors in the browser log whose I'm asserting for in test cleanup.