# Does, protractor 5.1.2 support Edge and Safari 10 now?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to run protractor 5.1.2 against MicrosoftEdge, and it fails with the message: Angular could not be found on the page https://someaddress/.If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular. If i turn off waitForAngularEnabled (set it false) it starts to work, and i have the same situation against Safari 10. But the same tests work fine against last versions of Chrome, Fierfox and IE. Does anyone know it's supported in Safari 10 and Edge "waitForAngular"? There is no active issuees in github. Does anyone tests against these browsers?
Angula version: AngularJS v1.5.8

Comment: are you using anguarjs (1) or angular (2, 4, ...)?

Comment: I use angularjs

Comment: the protractor world is quite complex, it's very difficult to tell what the problem could be - I see a lot of issues relate to this message on github. my only suggestion is to try a downgrade of protractor to previous versions and see if the issue is the same - because the newest versions of protractor are probably focusing on angular2+ more

Comment: Thank you! I've just tried to downgrade to previous version (5.0.0), result the same. How do you think should I report some issue?

Comment: tried also protrctor 4.0.14, result same

Comment: but where exactly are you using `waitForAngular` ? - [some say it shouldn't really be needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882671/protractor-where-to-use-browser-waitforangular)

Comment: I'm not using it specially, it's just enabled, and used byself when it needed, it's an feature of protractor (it doesn't make sense for me to use protractor without it). "Before performing any action, Protractor waits until there are no pending asynchronous tasks in your Angular application. This means that all timeouts and http requests are finished."

Comment: Created the issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4298

Comment: I am running into the same issues. I might be leaving protractor soon unfortunately due to this. I see so many bugs reported, but not a lot of attention.