# protractor: How to find element by exact text?

Tags: protractor

testing applications encountered another problem. I need to click element by exact text, so i found a solution where I use cssContainingText and each,then if statment to comapre text and select certain element, but I think maybe is a better solution for that purpous?

Second questions: somewhere on stackoverflow I read that

```
element.click().then(){
dosomething;
});
```

will cause that 'dosomething;' will perform after click, I try this and it doesn't work, how to make that 'dosomething;' will perform after click;

Answer (score 20):

You can use `by.xpath` as a selector:

**By exact text**

```
element(by.xpath('.//*[.="text"]'))
```

**By css class with exact text**

```
element(by.xpath('.//*[.="text" and class="some-css-class"]'))
```

You can find a lot of xpath examples [online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx). There's also a [tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) you can use.

Comment: you solution give me the same result as I have, If I have element with name like button1 and button12 it will find button1 and button12. I want find element by exact text but only one

Comment: It should be working. Please post your html and selectors

Comment: i don't know that you understand me correctly. for example. I have two buttons with text: button1 and button12. If i write element(by.xpath('.//*[.="button1"]')) I only want find button1

Comment: That's exactly what should happen and precisely how it works on my end.

Answer (score 5):

1) Delian has correct answer, but in many cases the element content has additional whitespaces, so you need to trim them:

```js
getElementsByText: function (text, parentXpathSelector) {
    parentXpathSelector = parentXpathSelector || '//';
    return element(by.xpath(parentXpathSelector + '*[normalize-space(text())="' + text + '"]'));
}
```

2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/21785088/3147680

Answer (score 0):

Xpath is elegant but not so easy to read if someone else needs look at the code. I often pick an element in a repeater by only using cssContainingText and chained by.css. 
example:`element(by.css('.dropdown-menu')).element(by.cssContainingText('span', constants.STATUS.PENDING)).click();`
sure it might be slower than xpath. I realy don't now. But managable comes first

Comment: That works well except for when you have multiple items and one is a substring of another. `cssContainingText` will match both.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const allOptions = element.all(by.css('css-class'));
            allOptions.filter( (elem) => {
                return elem.getText().then((text) => {
                    return exact-text === text;
                });
            }).first().click();
```

Comment: The solution is working fine with me ! 
can i know why (-1) ? please :)