# How to wait for element or wait for element to be clickable in protractor?

Tags: protractor, wait

How to use wait for element to be clickable and wait for element to be present in protractor? I know this will help only with 1 element. Not for all.

For Example:-

Here is the website link, I am trying to automate using protractor and I do not want to use sleep in any case.

Steps to reproduce:-

1. Navigate to https://www.celebritycruises.com.
2. Click on Find A Cruise at top left corner and click on Find Cruise button.
3. It will be navigated to this link - celebritycruises.com/spa/#/itinerary-search.
4. Now here is the thing, This page takes time to load. So, I am trying to wait for the element or wait for element to be clickable. But it is getting failed.

   browser.get('https://www.celebritycruises.com');

   ```
   var pop = element(by.css('a.popover-find-cruise'));
   pop.click().then(function() {

   element.all(by.css('.cta.find-cruise-button button')).last().click();

   });

   var dta = element(by.css('.itinerary-search.spa #nav-departure-date'));

   var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
   browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(dta), 30000);

   dta.click();
   ```

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Please post the error, "It is getting failed" is not useful information

Comment: Nevermind, that page isn't angular from what I can see so im assuming you are getting a synchronous timeout from angular.  Please read https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md or other docs on how to use protractor with non-angular apps, such as http://ng-learn.org/2014/02/Protractor_Testing_With_Angular_And_Non_Angular_Sites/

Comment: Did you read this article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748442/protractor-how-to-wait-for-page-complete-after-click-a-button?rq=1