# Protractor browser.wait doesn't work with element(by()) on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, webdriver, protractor

For what reason(s) could this code fail (*no element found*)...

```
   element(by.id('loginButton')).click(); // triggers route change
   browser.wait(element(by.tagName('myComponent')).isPresent(), 10000, 'timeout');
   element(by.tagName('myComponent')).click();
```

...while this code works ?

```
   element(by.id('loginButton')).click(); // triggers route change
   const eC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
   browser.wait(eC.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName('myComponent'))), 10000, 'timeout');
   element(by.tagName('myComponent')).click();
```

I'm working with Angular 5.2.5, Protractor 5.3.0 and Jasmine 2.8.0.

*May be related*: I could also have asked why I need to add a `browser.wait()` while `element(by())` is supposed to be automatically added in the ControlFlow by Protractor, but there are already lots of related questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748442/protractor-how-to-wait-for-page-complete-after-click-a-button), [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/909), [there](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2358), [there](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2887),...), with no clear answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a not-so obvious difference between the two . But the webdriver [docs](http://nr-synthetics-sw-jsdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/module_selenium-webdriver_phantomjs_class_Driver.html) are clear about this.

`eC.visibilityOf(...)` - **Returns a function**. browser.wait() repeatedly evaluates functions until they return true.

`isPresent()` - **Returns a promise**. browser.wait() does not / cannot repeatedly evalute promises(!)  browser.wait() will continue immediately when the promise resolves , regardless of whether it returns true or false.

If you want to use isPresent() you can wrap it in a **function**. This allows webdriver to call it over and over.

```
 browser.wait(() => element(by.tagName('myComponent')).isPresent(), 10000, 'timeout');
```

Works exactly as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

The two statements are not equivalent as such. I created a simple page like below

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="first_name">Tarun</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerText = 'lalwani';
            div.id = 'last_name';
            setTimeout( () => document.body.appendChild(div),  3000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a simple test like below

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
    it('should add a todo', async function() {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

        browser.get('http://0.0.0.0:8000');

        const eC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        browser.wait(element(by.id('last_name')).isPresent(), 10000, 'timeout');
    });
});
```

When you run you will find the output is

```
Started
...
1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.617 seconds
```

Now if you change the code to

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
    it('should add a todo', async function() {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

        browser.get('http://0.0.0.0:8000');

        const eC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        browser.wait(eC.visibilityOf(element(by.id('last_name'))), 10000, 'timeout');

    });
});
```

The output of the same is below

```
Started
...
1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 3.398 seconds
```

As you can see the `visibilityOf` actually waited for the object to appear while the previous one didn't.

This is because the controlFlow will make `isPresent` get executed and return the promise returning value of true/false to the wait. While `visibilityOf` will return a function that the `wait` can check by calling again and again.

You can verify this by adding below in the test

```
console.log(typeof eC.visibilityOf(element(by.id('last_name'))))
console.log(typeof element(by.id('last_name')))
```

The output of same is

```
function
object
```

So the assumption your below two statements are same is wrong and that is why you don't get the correct results with the first one

```
browser.wait(element(by.tagName('myComponent')).isPresent(), 10000, 'timeout');
browser.wait(eC.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName('myComponent'))), 10000, 'timeout');
```