# protractor id click is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I am using protractor for e2e. THe code below opens my browser just fine but does not click on the id and fails after waiting for a while. what am I missing

```
describe('Craigslist automation', function() {
    browser.get('http://finance.yahoo.com');
    it('should greet the named user', function() {

        var postLink = element(by.id('yucs-top-news'));
        postLink.click();
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();

    });
});
```

here is the stack trace

```
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was: 
WebDriver.executeScript()
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:302:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.executeAsyncScript (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:538:15)
    at [object Object].Protractor.get (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:1248:15)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/spec/example_spec.js:42:13)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
    at describe (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/spec/example_spec.js:41:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
F

Failures:

  1) Craigslist automation should greet the named user
   Message:
     timeout: timed out after 10000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 11.011 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1640
      var result = fn();
                   ^
Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://finance.yahoo.com/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
    at /Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:1254:17
    at /Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1640:20)
    at notify (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:444:12)
    at notifyAll (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:422:7)
    at resolve (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:400:7)
    at fulfill (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:512:5)
    at Object.webdriver.promise.asap (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:758:5)
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1651:25)
    at notify (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:444:12)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.executeScript()
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:302:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.executeAsyncScript (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:538:15)
    at [object Object].Protractor.get (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:1248:15)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/spec/example_spec.js:42:13)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
    at describe (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/spec/example_spec.js:41:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.quit()
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:302:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.quit (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:375:21)
    at [object Object].HostedDriverProvider.teardownEnv (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/hosted.js:47:16)
    at driverprovider_.setupEnv.then.then.then.then.passed (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:280:35)
    at _fulfilled (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:573:44
    at flush (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`protractor`](https://github.com/angular/protractor) is an e2e testing framework **for angular apps**. As far as I see, `http://finance.yahoo.com` is not an angular application, which the error is saying about:

> Error: Angular could not be found on the page
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/ : retries looking for angular exceeded

But, you can still use `protractor` with for a non-angular site by switching off synchronization or interacting with a `driver` object directly, see:

- [how to use Protractor on non angularjs website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927652/how-to-use-protractor-on-non-angularjs-website)