# Protractor basic fundamental questions - low on the learning curve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

After working with Eclipse/JUnit/webdriver for few months, and now, trying to come up to speed with Protractor, I am forced to fall back and submit some basic questions for you java/js experts.

1. Why in Protractor, do I have to invoke direct reference of "browser.driver."
   when testing Non-Angular web pages versus in Eclipse/Junit/weddriver I just instantiate the webdriver object?
2. In Protractor, when referencing the "browser.driver" directly, do I always have to use the element finder method "browser.driver.findElement"(by."  or is the method overloaded such that "browser.driver.element(By." will also work?

Answer (score 1):

You *don't need to use `browser.driver` directly*.

The only common and important difference between testing an angular site and a non-angular one is `browser.ignoreSynchronization` boolean flag.

Aside from that, continue using global `browser` object and `element` notation. For example:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get("http://mysite")

element(by.css("div.footer a#contactus")).click();
```

See also:

- [how to use Protractor on non angularjs website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927652/how-to-use-protractor-on-non-angularjs-website)
- [Protractor - Testing Angular and Non Angular Sites](http://ng-learn.org/2014/02/Protractor_Testing_With_Angular_And_Non_Angular_Sites/)
- [What is browser.ignoreSynchronization in protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808463/what-is-browser-ignoresynchronization-in-protractor)