# How can I use Protractor with google.com?

Tags: testing, selenium, protractor

google.com isn't an Angular app, but Protractor should still be able to test it, right? I've been trying to do a simple test of a search, but keep running to errors.

the spec:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

describe('Google Demo', function() {
  it('Should Search', function() {
    browser.get('http://google.com/');
    browser.wait(element(By.id('q')).isPresent);
    element(By.id('q')).sendKeys('please work');
  });
});
```

the error is:

```
Failures:

1) Google Demo Should Search
 Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you should try **By.name('q')** instead of **By.id('q')**.

Comment: Same results, Sakshi Singla

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927652/how-to-use-protractor-on-non-angularjs-website?

Comment: i recommend using this: https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor
so you know if it works, its a great tool

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since it's a non-Angular app, you need to use `browser.driver` instead of just `browser`. [GitHub Link for non-angular app](https://github.com/sakshisingla/Protractor-Non-Angular-Tests/wiki/Creating-test-scripts-using-Protractor-for-non-angular-application)

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

describe('Google Demo', function() {
  it('Should Search', function() {
    browser.driver.get('http://google.com/');   
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('q')).sendKeys('please work');
  });
});
```

This is working on my system!

Answer (score 0):

this also works for non angular apps

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

```html
describe('Google search', function() {
    it('should search a text as GURU99', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get('https://www.google.com');
    element(by.name("q")).sendKeys('test')
    browser.sleep(5000);

});
});
```