# For E2E Testing: which is better selenium or protractor for following web stack (Angular, Python and MongoDB)?

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I recently came to know about protractor framework which provides end to end testing for angular applications.

I would like to know, which test framework suits better for following webstack, either selenium or protractor

> Angular, Python and MongoDB.

I am going to use mozilla browser only.

Can anyone please provide your valueable suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> either selenium or protractor

This is an incorrect question. `Protractor` is itself selenium. Well, it is a wrapper around `WebDriverJS` - Javascript selenium bindings. And a quite convenient wrapper with a nice and documented API. It is a perfect choice for both Angular and non-Angular applications (you would need to [turn the sync off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927652/how-to-use-protractor-on-non-angularjs-website)).

Answer (score 1):

Protractor is based off using Selenium webdrivers.  If you have an Angular app for your entire front-end, I would go with Protractor.  If you are going to have a mixed front-end environment, you may want to go with Selenium only.