# Protractor - Chrome - very slow

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to use protractor for my non-angular application. Basically once the site is launched, i am trying to get the names of all the radio buttons.

the code is simple

```
$$(".radio").filter(function(elem,index){
    return elem.isDisplayed();
}).each(function(ele,index){
    console.log(ele.getAttribute("name"));
});
```

Why the protractor is very very slow?

Please click on the image to see it big to understand the issue.
From this log, to check 25 radio buttons, it takes 7 seconds!!!

My browser is chrome. Most of the machine config, you can get it in the log.

[image]

Comment: Since you're trying to use Protractor to test a non-Angular app, here is an answer to the same question you have asked from another post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927652/how-to-use-protractor-on-non-angularjs-website).

Comment: Are you sure this is a browser-specific issue? What happens in Firefox? Thanks.

Comment: @WayneK, I have the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` which is fine.

Comment: @alecxe, I did not even have FF. So i just installed and tried. It works fine in FF. Only chrome is very slow! Do you not see any issues like that? I also checked. It is not specific to my appn. Even for an angular demo site, it is slow in chrome.

Comment: @KitKarson could you post the test you are executing for the demo angular page? And the output you are getting with the execution time? Thanks.