# Clear input with protractor non-angular syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am testing a non-angular (javascript and HTML) site with protractor and selenium. I want to clear the input. I have used below commands

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('txtname')).clear();
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('txtEditGuestFname')).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "1234");
```

since i can not use angular syntax both the codes doesn't work to me.

Any other idea how to clear the input with simple javascript protractor supporting code?

Comment: Can you send keys only? Without clearing input?

Comment: Might help you with using protractor on a non-angular page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23198865/3561995

Comment: .sendKeys(' ') append the text to textbox not replace it. I want to clear the pre filled text and then want to enter my own text with .sendKeys()

Comment: Um, is this really from your code?  If so, there's a problem.  the first line clears one text field, and the second line calls sendKeys to a completely different text field.  If you want to clear first, you need to clear the same one you're going to sendKeys to.

Comment: the code i have sent is just an example (i know the text fields are different ). what i meant is i have used both the technique but it doesn't work. reason is my site is non-angular and those 2 codes are angular syntax.

Comment: Those 2 lines of code are not specific to angular or protractor, they are selenium webdriver syntax. They will work regardless of your site being angular.

Comment: i know those syntax are for angular, how can i clear a input in non-angular site?