# e2e testing for an application built in Polymer and Angular js

Tags: polymer, protractor, e2e-testing

We had built an application on angular js and we had used Jasmine & Protractor for e2e testing. Recently we migrated our application to Polymer js and Angular js.

Can we still use Jasmine & Protractor to do e2e testing across Polymer components?

I have come across web component tester e2e testing framework specifically built for polymer components but protractor is best suited for Angular js applications. So I'm not sure which e2e testing stack I should use for this scenario.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can and actually should stay with Protractor.

It's just that Protractor is a bit more flexible and rich when testing AngularJS application, but it *does not have to be an Angular under test*. Protractor wraps WebDriverJS - javascript selenium bindings and provides a lot of convenient concepts and utility functions for general end-to-end testing.

Few things to take into account:

- you will [turn the Protractor-to-Angular-and-back sync off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23198865/771848)
- with sync off, you would need to add [explicit waits](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) here and there to improve on reliability and robustness

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alecxe! Will protractor able to find the elements from a Polymer component as those reside in shadow dom?

Comment: @Ansuman sure, there is the "by deep css" location technique which can be relevant..