# Protractor - How to navigate to external non angular URL from an angular page

Tags: protractor

Using protractor, I want to load an external url (e.g. https://www.stackoverflow.com/) after performing some actions on  an angular page. If I try with the following code snippet, it hangs the test execution completely

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.driver.get('https://www.stackoverflow.com/');
```

Can anyone please help me out what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use Protractor on non angularjs website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927652/how-to-use-protractor-on-non-angularjs-website)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to push the function in control flow. try with below

// disable synchronization

```
browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
});
```

// execute your non-angular part

```
browser.get('https://www.stackoverflow.com/');
```

// enable synchronization again for back to angular page.

```
browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```