# Alternativa to Protractor for NON-angular project

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

I need to find the best testing tool for automation of front end in NON-angular project. I was told that Protractor has a bad performance for non-angular testing and was advised to use Puppeteer. However, I found that Puppeteer can run only for chrome. I need to test different browsers.

- Is protractor really bad for non-angular?
- What other libraries I can use as a replacement?

Comment: Why not selenium with webdriver js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927652/how-to-use-protractor-on-non-angularjs-website

Comment: Thanks, @BharathKumarS. The question is not how to use Protractor with non-Angular. The question is either to use it or not. I think, generally, Protractor is easier to use then Webdriver. But I used it in the past only with Angular. Not sure how efficient it will be with not Angular.

Comment: Our team used protractor for non angular site and it was successful.

Comment: I've had some good results using [webdriverio](http://webdriver.io). I actually migrated a testing framework I was working on from protractor to webdriverio a couple years ago. Surprisingly, it wasn't too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Use Protractor and ask naysayers to show study of slowness.