# Facing issue in protractor script execution after ag-grid version upgraded to 25.3

Tags: protractor, ag-grid

Facing issue in protractor script execution after ag-grid version upgraded to 25.3
Protractor version 7.0.0
Application angular version 12
ag-grid version 25.3
I am trying to test on Chrome

My scripts were working fine when ag-grid version was lower that 25.3 but now after developer updated ag-grid version scripts are not working and I am getting error of script timeout whenever trying to perform operations on grid(note it is giving problem when grid is in editable mode)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what ag-grid is, but what you probably need to do is to disable waiting for angular before interacting with grid and enabling it back when done

```
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); // to disable
// interact with your grid
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); // to enable
console.log(await browser.waitForAngularEnabled()); // to log current state
```

but make sure the page is angular ready before you turn off this feature in protractor, otherwise it won't work

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111219/9150146 for more info